# Is it acceptable to say "badly efficient"

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

If you didn't want to say someone is "inefficient", how would you concisely describe someone who has bad efficiency - badly/poorly efficient doesn't sound quite right, or is this ok?

Comment: I would use *low efficiency* instead of *bad efficiency*. You could say that something is *not very efficient*.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան I wanted to know if it was correct to say "Dan is ______" without saying inefficient. Upvote because answer is useful - Dan is not very efficient would work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Inefficient* plainly is the most efficient word to use here, but if for some reason you prefer innuendo or euphemism, consider words or phrases like *less than perfect*, *ineffective*, *fritterer*, *fiddler*, *unfocussed*, *overly meticulous*, *indirect*, *wasteful*, *roundabout*.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head there. I can't imagine why anyone would want to avoid the normal word *unless* they wanted an insinuating or euphemistic nuance. Which is easy for us Brits, because we'd just say *"He has an **interesting** approach to efficiency"* (in such contexts, *interesting = crap, useless, not worth bothering with* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Define *interesting*." "Oh god, oh god, we're all gonna die?"

Comment: @Martha: I suspect you're trying to trick me into spending another whole afternoon trapped in [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThisIsGonnaSuck). But as it happens, I watched [Serenity](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/quotes) last week, so I knew I'd be bound to find that quote on IMDB.

Answer (score 1):

"Less than efficient" may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in your comment to @Armen, saying ***Dan is not very efficient*** is a perfectly acceptable way (at least in British England) of saying that his efficiency is not very good. (In fact, it's the phrase I immediately thought of when reading your question and *before* reading the comments I mentioned.)